# Spring Batch Admin: Schedule new jobs through web GUI

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

A newbie question on Sprint Batch Admin.

My requirement is that the user should be able to schedule new jobs (passing some parameters for the job functionality) through a web UI. These jobs should be persistent, will be repetitive and could be cancelled or deleted. Also, a report could be generated for last run jobs and to list all the existing jobs with their next run dates.

Perhaps my most important requirement is that this should be possible "on the fly", not requiring redeploying the web-application or a server re-start.

Can this be done using Spring Batch Admin (I see that the guide talks about uploading an XML for adding a job but that seems tedious, if there is an API why shouldn't we be able to create a job on the fly through the Batch Admin Web UI)? Or does JDK Timer or Quartz support it?

Answer (score 1):

Once a job has been created, it can't be deleted, but it [can be stopped](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/reference/screenshots.html#Stop_an_Execution). Allowing deletion from DB is a risky operation, as Spring Batch might have already been started the job execution, but the DB has not been updated yet. If one removes the job at this moment, you have inconsistency.

Scheduling a new job is described in [Launch Job](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch-admin/reference/screenshots.html#Launch_Job). It is not possible to create new types of jobs, as jobs can generally have complicated configuration which is parsed only once when Spring Context is loaded.

Comment: Thanks. I want to determine whether its possible to Schedule jobs through a Web GUI, and whether Spring Batch or JDK Timer or Quartz Scheduler supports. So far what I have seen that in a web-application all of these expect jobs to be "configured" before-hand and would require the web-app to be "redeployed" rather than add the job "on the fly".

Comment: It is possible to schedule (= launch) a new job instance. It will be run by task executor, which can be asynchronous (you should define that in Spring config). Quartz is used to run job on schedule, you normally don't need Spring Admin console to run them, but probably to see the execution results. Job should be configured beforehand in respect to what should be done with data (read, chunk, modify, write), but the actual data (file, URL, whatever) can be passed via parameters. Of course one can use parameters to tune the processing itself, it's job task to interpret the meaning of parameters.

Comment: Thanks again! Your answer helps me understand now that ultimately we would need Quartz or Cron to run the jobs according to schedule with Spring Batch taking care of the actual execution process. Would you know if we could schedule jobs on the fly through a GUI for Quartz? so far I understood that you still need it pre-configured using, say, a properties file.

Comment: Ok got some clue at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267737/frontend-for-quartz

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic deployment (on the fly) of jobs and configurations, without requiring server restart, is a feature we implemented in Trooper Batch Profile - it is not exactly Spring Batch admin but builds on it. You continue to write your jobs using Spring batch, just the container changes for in Trooper you would use its Batch profile runtime. Screen shots and features are here : https://github.com/regunathb/Trooper/wiki/Writing-Batch-jobs-in-Trooper

Answer (score 0):

I think we can deploy the each spring batch job by a SBA. I mean each batch job will be compiled as a war file.  We deploy them together in server. In this way, we have the following visiting urls to monitor each jobs:

h t t p://bactchjobserver/job1

h t t p://bactchjobserver/job2

h t t p://bactchjobserver/job3

h t t p://bactchjobserver/job4

But the downside is that each war fill surely contains lib files, which make each war file like 10MB size.

At the same time, I tried to manually add new-job.xml to war-file\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\batch\jobs, and new-job.jar to war-file\WEB-INF\lib without stopping JBoss. It works. The new job can be showed in SBA UI and runnable.

But obviously this would lead much maintenance and trouble shooting. It is not implementable.